# I do not have access to some Power BI sheets

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

Clearly the system does not allow me to see some tables. Whether it is the tables linked to the module time or any other one. The same goes for the Purchase module, I have access to just some of the tables.

Can you guys help me understand why I cannot get access to these tables please?

[image]

note : i can access all of the sheet's records that i do not have access to on powerbi on another dynamics365 application, so i'm really confused why is that !

Comment: The tables on the left are filtered on "purchas", the data on the right is only a small preview. Which other tables are you expecting when applying that filter?

Comment: The right part yes just displays a preview but in my case when I select this table, and I try to see its contents, I only see the records which are displayed before the selection of the table. @Sander